# Problema com JavaFx

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Estou com problema quando adiciono um botão JFX que está presente na biblioteca Jfoenix. Ao abrir meu documento FXML, ele direciona certinho para o SceneBuilder, e dentro dele, da para utilizar todos os itens contidos na biblioteca Jfoenix.

Porém quando eu executo meu programa pelo netbeans para que ele possa mostrar como está ficando ele da erro, o problema que ele só da erro quando adiciono qualquer item da biblioteca JFX .

No exemplo abaixo só tem um AnchorPane e um JFXbutton e ele apresenta os seguintes erros:

> ```
> Copying 13 files to C:\Users\Igor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\dist\run728892560
> jfx-project-run:
> Executing C:\Users\Igor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\dist\run728892560\JavaFXApplication1.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre/bin/java
> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>     at javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1.start(JavaFXApplication1.java:22)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>     ... 1 more
> Exception running application javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1
> Java Result: 1
> Deleting directory C:\Users\Igor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\dist\run728892560
> jfxsa-run:
> CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1 segundo)
> ```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Desenterrando pergunta para referência futura:

O verdadeiro problema conforme o  *stack trace* é a versão do Java:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

No caso a versão em questão do Jfoenix requer o Java 9 (`class file version 53.0`) e a aplicação estava rodando no Java 8 (`52.0`).

Para uma lista  completa de versões de classe veja os *offsets* 6 e 7 da tabela no seguinte artigo: [Wikipedia - Java class file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) (em inglês).

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que adicionar a biblioteca dentro do netbeans. Vá em Arquivo, Propriedades do Projeto, Bibliotecas, Adicionar JAR/Pasta.

Vá em propriedades do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora em Bibliotecas, click em Adicionar JAR/Pasta, selecione o .Jar do Jfoenix.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Click em Ok, agora é só reconstruir o projeto.

Referencia:
https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/62